# How to recieve list of users who shared my link on facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

i'm trying to get list of users who shared my link on facebook. I need name and ID. I'm reading about opengraph API, but heard that protected by facebook privacy, is it right?

Second try: if i use JS SDK like this

```
 FB.ui(
  {
    method: 'share',
    href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
  },
  // callback
  function(response) {
    if (response && !response.error_message) {
      alert('Posting completed.');
    } else {
      alert('Error while posting.');
    }
  }
);
```

can i get name or id who share this link as callback data?

Can i even do it?

Thnx

Comment: see my answer. may i ask what for you need to know the name and id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would only be possible if the user would be authorized in your App - with the `publish_actions` permission. Only in that case you can be sure that the user really shared something, because you will get the Post ID in the callback.

But: You will definitely not get `publish_actions` approved in the review process just for that.